# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException In Jboss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x

We have migrated from Jboss 6 to JBoss 7 after migration for some of rest controllers while sending Json we got following error:

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.listgroup.ready.service.config.Domain["class1"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.listgroup.ready.service.config.Table["class2"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.listgroup.ready.service.config.Column["class3"]->com.listgroup.skeleton.FieldType["class4"]->com.listgroup.skeleton.FieldType["class4"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:284)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:921)

This is not getting replicating for tomcat also.

Answer (score 0):

I found from logs that Jboss is using their own libraries instead of WEB-INF/lib libraries.

To avoid this I have added jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in my WEB-INF.
contents of jboss-deployment-structure.xml file are :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        <!-- end of logger service exclusions -->        
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```